# PHP SQL how the get the exact count from a table

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables with the following columns:

- FAMILY - id, ...
- PRODUCTS - id, idfamily, type, ...

`FAMILY` & `PRODUCTS` are connected with `family.id = products.idfamily`.

I'm doing pagination over families with filters based on products types, so I'm trying to get the exact count of `FAMILY` containing almost one product with a specific type.

First query is ok, I get all the families:

```
if (!isset($_GET['type']) || $_GET['type'] == 'all') {
    $query_family=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM family");  
}
$count=mysql_num_rows($query_family);
// result = 166
```

Unfortunately, the following query is wrong:

```
} else {
    $query_family=mysql_query("
      SELECT * FROM family f LEFT JOIN products p ON f.id = p.idfamily  
      WHERE p.type = '$_GET[type]' 
    ");  
}
$count=mysql_num_rows($query_family);
// result = 500+
```

it's wrong because I get *all* the products with a type, but **I'm trying to get the number of families containing products with the selected type** (`$_GET[type]`).

Thank you

Comment: SELECT distinct  * FROM /*-----*/ p.type = '{$_GET[type]}'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have
`SELECT distinct  f.id from family f LEFT JOIN products p on f.id = p.idfamily WHERE p.type = '$_GET[type]'` in the second query 
I think.

Answer (score 1):

And you don't have to use mysql_num_rows, you can get the right number directly from mysql:

```
$query = "SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT f.id) ".
    "FROM family f ".
    "LEFT JOIN products p ON f.id = p.idfamily ".
    "WHERE p.type = '".$_GET['type']."'";
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try below code:

```
$query_family=mysql_query("
SELECT COUNT(f.id) AS cnt FROM family f 
INNER JOIN products p ON f.id = p.idfamily  
WHERE p.type = '$_GET[type]'");
```

Also try to use mysqli not mysql.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as nbr FROM family 
INNER JOIN products ON products.idfamily = family.id
WHERE product.type = ".intval($_GET['type'])."
GROUP BY family.id
```

Avoid the mysql_ driver, use PDO or mysqli instead. Don't forget to protect you from sql injections too.

Answer (score 1):

To get the count of families with a specified type, use

```
 SELECT * FROM family f INNER JOIN products p ON f.id = p.idfamily  
WHERE IFNULL(p.type, 'notspecified') = '$_GET[type]'
```

With INNER JOIN instead of LFET JOIN you get only rows where a connection between f.id and p.idfamily exist. By LEFT JOIN, all family rows are returned with NULL values in the fields of product table.
So when p.type is NULL, your p.type = '$_GET[type]' evaluates always to NULL, and your filtering will not work as expected. For this reason, use IFNULL.

Answer (score -1):

Use `INNER JOIN` instead of `LEFT`.